# Showing Buttons in Oracle Apex with Server Side Condition dependent on Page Item Value?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

I am currently struggling with Oracle Apex, trying to show a Button, when the Value of a Page Item is greater than Zero (numeric).

Figured the Server Side Condition (SQL Expression) would be the best Idea and my SQL Code is:

```
    If :PAGE_ITEM > 0 then
      Return True;
    else
       Return False;
    End if;
```

I am however getting the error: ORA-06550: line 1, column 37: ORA-00920: invalid relational operator.

Using the Server-Side-Condition "Item = Value" with my Item selected and the Value being 0 did not work as well...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your expression syntax is incorrect for "SQL Expression" type.  It is appropriate for the "PL/SQL Function Body" type.

However, the most appropriate type for this in my opinion is "PL/SQL Expression", with the simple expression:

```
:PAGE_ITEM > 0
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! Worked perfectly!